# Reuse NSPredicate for new variable substitute

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nspredicate

Can I reuse NSPredicate for new variable substitute? My NSPredicate is rather simple:

```
NSPredicate *userPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id == %@",userID];
```

The userID is generated at run-time with different value, right now for each userID I need to create a NSPredicate. So is it possible I can reuse my NSPredicate ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yep, you can do this with a variable:

```
NSPredicate *userPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id == $user"];
```

Save that predicate somewhere, then do this when you need to actually start filtering stuff:

```
NSDictionary *sub = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:user forKey:@"user"];
NSPredicate *filter = [userPredicate predicateWithSubstitutionVariables:sub];
```

This is a much more efficient way to reuse a predicate, because parsing the format string (which can be pretty expensive) only happens once.

Comment: do you know if we can apply variable substitution to keys ? Actually seems they are replaced with quotation marks, and making the query unusable.

Comment: @Leonardo I don't believe so. AFAIK, variables can only be replaced by constant values, not key paths.

Comment: Can I have multiple substitutions with a single key?

Comment: @atreat yep, you can have `$user` show up multiple times in the predicate.

Comment: @PsychoDad The docs say "The receiver itself is not modified by this method..." so I would assume so.

Comment: @Leonardo @DaveDeLong You can do variable substitution with keys by using `["myKey": NSExpression(forKeyPath: theKey)]` in your substitution dictionary.

Comment: @DaveDeLong is there any best practice when using NSCompoundPredicate to create a complex predicate? I want to create a filter for data in Core Data, with some parameters that are optionals (e.g. items tagged with X, Y, Z). Can I use the template only for simple predicate, then combine them using an NSCompoundPredicate? Would there be any impact on performances? Because some parameters are optionals, using templates will require many different templates, for all search scenario... Which would be a pain to maintain.