# NSPredicate with multiple statements

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data

I have `NSPredicate` with four statements/parameters. It seems like all of them isn't "included". It looks like this:

```
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"user.youFollow = 1 || user.userId = %@ && user.youMuted = 0 && postId >= %d", [AppController sharedAppController].currentUser.userId, self.currentMinId.integerValue];
```

It seems like the last part: `&& postId >= %d`, is ignored. If I try:

```
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"user.youFollow = 1 || user.userId = %@ && user.youMuted = 0 && postId = 0", [AppController sharedAppController].currentUser.userId, self.currentMinId.integerValue];
```

I get the same result (should be 0). I wonder how a predicate like this should look?

Comment: Have you tried with parenthesis? Just to see if it is a problem of precedence...

Comment: I have tried: `(user.youFollow = 1 || user.userId = %@) && (user.youMuted = 0 && postId >= %d)`.

Comment: What does `NSLog(@"%@", [predicate description]);` print?

Comment: you can try to remove some "piece" of your predicate (simplifying it) to see if the result is what you'd expect...

Comment: You must use parentheses when there are OR and AND operations in one logical condition. Also, use `==` instead of `=` for comparisons. Try to use `OR` and `AND` instead of `||` and `&&`. If you are comparing two strings, use `'` symbol: `user.userId == '%@'`.

Comment: @cevitcejbo: AND has higher precedence than OR in a predicate, but I agree that putting parentheses is better. - "==" and "=" are equivalent, same for "||" and "OR" etc. - Comparing strings with `user.userId == '%@'` is *wrong*, it will prevent from `%@` being substituted.

Comment: I tried `(user.youFollow == 1 || user.userId == %@) && (user.youMuted == 0 && postId >= %d)`, but I get the same results.

Comment: @Anders: I suggest that you show the actual value of the predicate (using NSLog, as I said above) and also what results you get and what results you expect.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks Martin, think I found the problem. The log was: `(user.youFollow == 1 OR user.userId == 5385) AND user.youMuted == 0 AND postId >= 0`, seems like the predicate gets executed before my (%@) iVar have the right value.

Comment: @Anders: Yes that is true. The arguments are evaluated and the values copied into the predicate, so changing them later has no effect on the predicate.

Comment: Is is possible to have a dynamic and changing variable in a predicate?

Comment: @Anders: There are "predicates with substitution variables", see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708541/reuse-nspredicate-for-new-variable-substitute .

Comment: @MartinR Thanks! The answer for the question have `Save that predicate somewhere [...]`. DO you have an idea or recommendation on where you could/should save a predicate?

Comment: @Anders Can you try code i have written?

Comment: @Anders Please accept answer if you got solution, thanks.

Comment: @Anders: Can you explain why you need a dynamic/changing variable in the predicate? Is the predicate used in a fetched results controller?

Comment: Yes, it is. `self.currentMinId` updates every time I fetch objects from a web service. I want to use this value in my predicate.

Comment: @Anders: In that case you have to re-create the predicate and the fetch request, see answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turned out in the discussion, the real problem is that the predicate is used in
a fetched results controller, and that the variables used in the predicate change over time.

In that case you have to re-create the predicate and the fetch request. This is documented
in **"Modifying the Fetch Request"** in the [NSFetchedResultsController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

So in your case, if `self.currentMinId` changes, you should

```
// create a new predicate with the updated variables:
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:...]
// create a new fetch request:
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = ...
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

// Delete the section cache if you use one (better don't use one!)
[self.fetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:...];

// Assign the new fetch request and re-fetch the data:
self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest = fetchRequest;
[self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];

// Reload the table view:
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: Thanks, got it to work! Small note, setFetchRequest is read only. I did: `self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest setPredicate...`.

Comment: @Anders: Thank you for the feedback! `self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest setPredicate:newPredicate]` might also work, perhaps you want to try that. In that case you need only a new predicate, but not a new fetch request.

Answer (score 3):

Can you try following code?

```
NSPredicate *youFollowPred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"user.youFollow == 1"];
NSPredicate *userIdPred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"user.userId == %@",[AppController sharedAppController].currentUser.userId];
NSPredicate *youMutedPred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"user.youMuted == 0"];
NSPredicate *postIdPred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"postId >= %d", self.currentMinId.integerValue];

NSPredicate *orPred = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:youFollowPred,userIdPred, nil]];

NSPredicate *andPred = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:youMutedPred,postIdPred, nil]];

NSPredicate *finalPred = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:orPred,andPred, nil]];
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Do you know if - `NSPredicate *postIdPred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"postId >= %d", self.currentMinId.integerValue]; - can have a dynamic `%d` variable. Need to update my predicate before I make new fetches.

Comment: @sunilz: Note that your code is exactly equivalent to the predicate `"(user.youFollow = 1 || user.userId = %@) && (user.youMuted = 0 && postId >= %d)", ...` .