# iOS CoreData / NSFetchedResultsController: Limit Result to 3 per Section

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

Imagine a News App. The App has multiple Channels with x News per Channel.
The first ViewController is an UITableViewController which shows all Channels as Sections and max. 3 News per Channel/Section.

I use a NSFetchedResultsController. How can I achieve that the NSFetchedResultsController fetches 3 News per Section?

Setting the fetchLimit in NSFetchRequest to 3 limits the whole result to 3 (= 1 section with 3 rows).

Any idea?

**Edit**

At the moment I use this code:
**UITableViewDataSource** Stuff (`NUMBER_OF_ITEMS_PER_CHANNEL = 3`):

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView*)tableView
{
    return [self.fetchedResultsController.sections count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [self.fetchedResultsController sections][section];
    NSInteger numberOfRows = [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
    if (numberOfRows > NUMBER_OF_ITEMS_PER_CHANNEL) {
        numberOfRows = NUMBER_OF_ITEMS_PER_CHANNEL;
    }
    return numberOfRows;

}
```

**NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate** Stuff:

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController*)controller
{
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController*)controller
    didChangeSection:(id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
             atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex
       forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
{
    UITableView* tableView = self.tableView;

    switch (type) {
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
        [tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
        [tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController*)controller
    didChangeObject:(id)anObject
        atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)theIndexPath
      forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
       newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)newIndexPath
{
    UITableView* tableView = self.tableView;

    switch (type) {
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
        if (newIndexPath.row < NUMBER_OF_ITEMS_PER_CHANNEL) {
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [controller sections][newIndexPath.section];
            NSInteger numberOfRowsInSection = [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
            if (numberOfRowsInSection > NUMBER_OF_ITEMS_PER_CHANNEL) {
                [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:NUMBER_OF_ITEMS_PER_CHANNEL inSection:newIndexPath.section]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            }
        }
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:theIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
        [self fetchedResultsController:controller configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:theIndexPath] atIndexPath:theIndexPath];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:theIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;
    }
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController*)controller
{
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

But when there are new News available (controller:didChangeObject.... is called with `type = NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert`) I get errors like this:

> CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught
>   from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to
>   -controllerDidChangeContent:.  Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 3.  The number of rows contained in an existing section
>   after the update (3) must be equal to the number of rows contained in
>   that section before the update (3), plus or minus the number of rows
>   inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 3 deleted) and plus
>   or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved
>   in, 0 moved out). with userInfo (null)

Any idea how to avoid this error?

Comment: I think in this case, you need to fetch the News entity itself rather than Channel entity but with a NSPredicate. So basically something like `NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
    @"channel == %@", channelName];
[fetchRequest2 setPredicate:predicate];` If you don't know how many channels, then I suppose you would have to perform 2 fetch operations, the first is to fetch all channels, then a second fetch operation which I mentioned above is where you set the fetch limit to 3

Comment: Thanks. But with a NSFetchedResultsController I can only use one NSFetchRequest or not?

Comment: Sorry Mike, I've never used NSFetchResultsController before, I tend to write all my fetch operations in my ViewControllers or in a PersistentStack Core Data singleton :P. One second point I also want to mention is, there is a way to **reuse predicates efficiently**: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708541/reuse-nspredicate-for-new-variable-substitute You should use this for substituting your Channel names I think.

Comment: You could instead amend your UITableView dataSource method `numberOfRowsInSection` to return min(3,section.numberOfObjects).

Comment: @pbasdf I edited my question and added my current code. As you can see it is like you mentioned. But that doesn't work either.

Comment: @mike I see you have found a work-around.  I think the error your were getting is because you should delete the row at index NUMBER_OF_ITEMS_PER_CHANNEL-1 (even though you have just inserted a row, the indexes are not updated until the tableView endUpdates call).  But in saying that, I can't understand why the error indicates there were 0 inserts.  So perhaps best to stick with your work-around!

Answer (score 0):

I found a **workaround** for my problem (which was avoiding the CoreData Error). But I didn't find a solution on how to get 3 News PER Channel (still interested in that one...).

In case one of you has the same problem - here my workaround:
Instead of deleting the last (third) row of a section and inserting a new one I just update the cells like this:

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController*)controller
    didChangeObject:(id)anObject
        atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)theIndexPath
      forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
       newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)newIndexPath
{

...

    switch (type) {
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
        if (newIndexPath.row < self.numberOfNewsItemsToFetch) {
            id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [controller sections][newIndexPath.section];
            NSInteger numberOfRowsInSection = [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
            if (numberOfRowsInSection >= self.numberOfNewsItemsToFetch) {
                NSIndexPath* indexPath = nil;
                for (NSUInteger i = newIndexPath.row; i < self.numberOfNewsItemsToFetch; i++) {
                    indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:newIndexPath.section];
                    [self fetchedResultsController:controller configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
                }
            }
            else {
                [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            }
        }
        break;
...
    }
}
```